# How to migrate this Template Haskell Lift instance to version 2.18

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I have a `Lift` instance that works with template-haskell 2.14, but won't compile with later versions.   Can someone explain what changes are needed?

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TemplateHaskell #-}

module LiftBS where

import Data.ByteString as B (ByteString, length, unpack)
import Data.ByteString.Unsafe (unsafePackAddressLen)
import Language.Haskell.TH (runIO, litE, stringPrimL)
import Language.Haskell.TH.Lift (Lift(lift))

instance Lift (IO B.ByteString) where
  lift bsio = do
    bs <- runIO bsio
    [|unsafePackAddressLen $(lift (B.length bs)) $(litE (stringPrimL (B.unpack bs))) :: IO ByteString|]
```

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to write that instance with `template-haskell-2.17.0.0` or newer. The type of `lift` is `Quote m => t -> m Exp`, and the `Quote` type class can't do IO.

Answer (score 6):

That's a sketchy instance of `Lift`. It's really not what `Lift` is for. It isn't an accident that the new type of `lift` rules out compile-time side effects. `Lift` is for serializing data structures, which this isn't even doing conceptually. If this were serializing the data structure passed to it, it would be splicing in a representation of the IO action. This is executing an action and serializing the result of that action. That's just not what someone unfamiliar with this code is going to expect to happen.

Also, all the work you're putting in to serialize the `ByteString` as its components hasn't been necessary since `bytestring-0.11.2.0`, when it got its own `Lift` instance.

But the real thing to do here is just write a function that does what you want:

```
atCompileTime :: Lift a => IO a -> Q Exp
atCompileTime act = do
    x <- runIO act
    [| pure x |]
```

It's not a `Lift` instance, so it can have a type that allows it to do what you want. It's not a `Lift` instance, so it can have a name that explains what it's actually doing. And as a bonus, it will work across a wide range of versions of template haskell.